# Can I get more information on an inbox notification for a comment on a deleted answer?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-answers, global-inbox

I have an inbox item but it looks like the person who answered the question and made response comment deleted his answer. Is there a way to see his/her id? I can see only part of the text in my inbox. Can I see it completely?

I wanted to let the poster know that his answer was working! Not sure why he deleted it.

Here's what I see in my inbox:

> comment on **Delete consecutives values in ArrayList of Int**
>
> "Give it a try... That's called twice because I'm already at the beginning of the next ran..." on [Delete consecutives values in ArrayList of Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518986/delete-consecutives-values-in-arraylist-of-int/16520185?noredirect=1#comment23719998_16520185)

Comment: The answer and comment are deleted - why would you need to know the ID of the commenter, now that the post they commented on is gone?

Comment: wanted to invite him to a chat and tell him it did work. i had not initiazeled test list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10k+ users can see deleted posts, including comments; visiting the link you shared I see:

> @tgkprog: Give it a try... That's called twice because I'm already at the beginning of the next range at that time: e.g.: with [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], the iterator is already at "5" when it starts to look back, and it needs to remove "2", not "3". According to the javadoc, the first call to previous returns "5" again. – [Costi Ciudatu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262683/costi-ciudatu).

The poster of that answer unfortunately did not comment anywhere on your question, so you'd have to find *another* post of his to be able to reply to him or invite him to a chat.

Comment: see it where? how? thanks

Comment: @tgkprog: I just went to your question and I can see the comment in question there.

Comment: hmm you mean cause you have a high karma you can see deleted items?

Comment: @tgkprog: Yes, I have over 10.000 rep on Stack Overflow, so I can see deleted posts.

Comment: oh i understand 10k+ users now ... users with karma/ rep of 10k+ can view ...